# How to count the intersection of two sets when there are relations inside the set?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm very much a beginner in discrete mathematics. I'd love some guidance on this question.

> Here are two sets: 
>   $$A:=\{ \{1,2\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,4\} \}$$ and 
>   $$B:=\{\{1,4\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{4,2\} \}.$$
>   How large is $|A∩B|$?

I assumed that this represents two multi-sets and then used the formula of taking the min of these two sets. I know this is not quite correct. Is this a multi-set? And how would I go about finding the intersection?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95469/discussion-on-question-by-katie-melosto-how-to-count-the-intersection-of-two-set).

Answer (score 5):

$$A\cap B = \{x\in A \text{ and } x\in B\} = \{ \{1,4\},\{4,2\}\}$$

Note that although in $A$ the set $S=\{2,4\}$ looks different than it does in $B$ (where it's shown as $\{4,2\}$) that these are still the same objects (as ordering within sets has no significance), and as such should be included in the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Multisets are sets where you are allowed to have elements appear multiple times.  Sets are sets where the elements can only appear once.  In neither does order matter.

As "multiple" can include $1$ all sets are also multisets but not all multisets are sets.

As these sets do *not* have any multiple elements they are plain old ordinary sets.

Theo C.s answer shows you that as plain old ordinary sets the only elements in both $A$ and $B$ are $\{1,4\}$ and $\{2,4\}$ (which is the same thing as $\{4,2\}$.

But *if* you wanted to use the minimum rule of multisets you could.  It's more complicated but you can use it.

$m_A (\{1,2\}) = 1$ because $\{1,2\}$ appears one time in $A$.$m_B(\{1,2\}) = 0$ because $\{1,2\}$ appears zero times in $B$.  So $m_{A\cap B} (\{1,2\}) = \min(m_A (\{1,2\}),m_B(\{1,2\})) = \min (1,0) = 0$.  So $\{1,2\}$ appears $0$ times  in $A\cap B$.

$m_A(\{1,4\}) = 1; m_B(\{1,4\}) = 1$ and $m_{A\cap B}(\{1,4\}) = \min(1,1) =1$ so $\{1,4\}$ appears $1$ time in $A \cap B$.

And so on.

$m_A(\{2,4\}) = 1$ and $m_B(\{2,4\}) = m_B(\{4,2\}) = 1$ so $\{2,4\}\in A\cap B$ but for

$\{1\}, \{2\}$ the $m_A$ of thes are $0$ and the $\min$ are $0$ so they don't appear either.

So the minimum rule gives the same answer.